# VBA queries return data beyond end date

Tags: sql, vba

I am running a VBA query which returns data beyond end date  .

The code is as follows:

```
startdate = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value, "####")
enddate = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3").Value, "####")

Set conn = New ADODB.connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
connection = "provider = sqloledb ; data source = &user; initial catalog = &data ; integrated security = sspi ; "
conn.Open connection
Set rs = conn.Execute("select * from sale_table where datetime   >= " & startdate & " and datetime <=  " & enddate & "")

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Sheets(1).Range("I12").CopyFromRecordset rs
Else
    MsgBox ("no record")
End If
```

if enddate = 31/08/2016
result shown upto 02/09/2016 ( two days beyond end date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date formatting is the problem:

```
startdate = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value, "####")
enddate = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3").Value, "####")
```

These will produce *date serials*, or the number of days elapsed since January 1st, 1900. For 31/08/2016 (08/31/2016 for those in the US), your `enddate` will be 42613 when using Excel.

In SQL Server, you can either use `DATEADD(DAY, ..., ...)` or `CAST( ... AS DATETIME)` to convert this to a date. Implicitly, when you perform a logical operation against a date serial i.e. `<= enddate` or `>= startdate` it'll convert that serial into a `datetime`.

However, if you have tried `DATEADD` or `CAST` on 42613 in SQL Server you'll notice it returns 02/09/2016 (US: 09/02/2016) which is why your returned data is beyond the end date. Also, if you tried `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-31', '1900-01-01')` it returns 42611 on SQL Server; 2 days difference to Excel's interpretation of 31/08/2016 date serial.

Why is this?

Mr Chip Pearson explains it in [Dates and Times in Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm), but I'll summarize it. Keep in mind that when I say *date serial* I mean *days elapsed since 01/01/1900*. Both in Excel and SQL Server, default date value is 01/01/1900. However:

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0

00/01/1900 (US: 01/00/1900) is not a valid date. So already we have to offset any Excel date serial by -1. Why so?

> The number 1 represents 1900-Jan-1.  It should be noted that the number 0 does not represent 1899-Dec-31. Actually, this number is one greater than the actual number of days.  This is because Excel behaves as if the date 1900-Feb-29 existed.  It did not.  The year 1900 was not a leap year (the year 2000 is a leap year).  In Excel, the day after 1900-Feb-28 is 1900-Feb-29.  In reality, the day after 1900-Feb-28  was 1900-Mar-1 .  This is not a "bug".  Indeed, it is by design.

So, in your particular case, since date serial 1 represents 01/01/1900 in Excel (because date serial 0 is 00/01/1900) which is first of your extra 2 days and the leap year 2000 has 366 days rather than 365 which is your second extra day, that's why it's returning data up to and including 02/09/2016.

In short, you need to account for Excel's date representation as being days from 00/01/1900 rather than from 01/01/1900 and also any leap years when using an Excel date serial in a SQL Server statement.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathon for your  explanation about the issue  .  I am new to programming  , I am not able to get my query working  . if i format dates as 
startdate = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: You'd need to include single quotes either side of the date value for it to be interpreted by your SQL database. So `where datetime   >= '" & startdate & "' and datetime <=  '" & enddate & "' "`